# Pandas Yearly analyses and then by month

Tags: python, pandas

I am analysing a time series in pandas from 20 unique years. I would like to split it up by individual years which I have done already, although I am having trouble with getting a monthly analysis. I would like to analyse by Month but not for each year. What I would like to do is get the count of the months from 1996 - 2016 IE(Jan - the number of publishers, feb - the number of publishers) rather than a monthly analysis of each year I would like a total for all my years counted by months.

[The image is here from a sample of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It3PI.png)

So my dataframe is called combined and i want to group it by "publisher"

```
combined['Platform'].resample("M").count()
1996-09-30     2
1996-10-31     0
1996-11-30    31
1996-12-31    10
1997-01-31    10
1997-02-28     4
1997-03-31     6
1997-04-30     9
1997-05-31    11
1997-06-30     6
1997-07-31     4
1997-08-31     8
1997-09-30    15
1997-10-31    19
1997-11-30    20
1997-12-31     8
1998-01-31     9
1998-02-28     2
1998-03-31    11
1998-04-30     7
```

The above code is resampling by month per year. However what I am looking for is something like this :

```
01 2
02 3
03 3
04 5
05 8 
06 9 
07 10 
08 11
09 12
10 12 
11 15 
12 13
```

I am looking to resample by month but across all the 20 years rather than each individual year

Comment: I have fixed it now hopefully makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%B'))['Publisher'].count()
```

You want to group the cells by Month name and then do the `count` operation.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I was looking for , thanks for the help !